# Trace and transformations of a matrix

Tags: matrices, trace

I have the following expression

$$T = \operatorname{Trace}(AMA')$$

where $M$ is a square $n\times n$ matrix, and $A$ is a $m \times n$ matrix, both full-rank. The goal I want to achieve is that I do not want any of the off-diagonal elements of $M$ to enter into the equation for $T$. Therefore I am looking for the necessary condition on $A$ such that this is the case. I already know that a sufficient condition is the fact that $A$ is diagonal - in this case, none of the off-diagonal elements of $M$ will enter into the formula for the trace. However, I am hoping that there is a more general condition on $A$ such that this is true.

For example, lets say that 
\begin{equation}
{\bf A} = 
\begin{bmatrix} a&b\\c&d\\e&f \end{bmatrix}.
\end{equation}

and

\begin{equation}
{\bf M} = 
\begin{bmatrix} g&h\\i&j \end{bmatrix}.
\end{equation}

Clearly $\operatorname{Trace} (M)$ is a function of $g$ and $j$ only. So I am looking for the necessary conditions on the matrix $A$ such that $\operatorname{Trace} (AMA')$ is also a function of $g,j$, and the entries of $A$, but not a function of $i$ and $h$.

Any help or hints would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you,

Paul

Comment: not consistent notation; the way you wrote $A,$ the expression $A'M$ is not legal, assuming you mean transpose. But $AM$ is defined.

Comment: In the specific case you wrote down, the trace of $AMA^t$ is independent of $i$ and $j$ if and only if $ab+cd+ef=0$ (seen by brute force calculation).

Comment: @Will Jagy, thank you for your note -- I was careless and switched the order of A and A'. I edited my post accordingly.

Comment: @Gren Martin, thank you and that is a good start. I guess I am asking more general about what form such matrices would take. I suppose any matrix where each row has only one non-zero entry would do the trick. Though that is still not completely general.

Comment: wait... I just realized the answer is quite obvious. by definition, A has to be any matrix with orthogonal columns.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the help of some commenters, A is a matrix with orthogonal columns. Just to give some background on why I was asking this question in case anyone is interested:

I was trying to solve a multidimensional HJB equation, which involved as one of its terms

Trace(AHA'), where H is the hessian matrix. In my case I had the freedom to pick the matrix A freely as long as it was full-rank. The reason I didn't want the off-diagonal elements of H to affect the trace is that would mean I wouldn't have to deal with cross-derivatives in my PDE system. Therefore picking the correct A means that I have a decoupled system of PDEs which is easier to solve.

-Paul